# Синтаксис объявления структуры в Си

Tags: c, структуры

Нет, правда. Поверхностно я знаю C но это... новый синтаксис C99 наверное:

```
struct node {
    int payload;
    int height;
    struct node *kid[2];
} dummy = {0, 0, {&dummy, &dummy}}, *nnil = &dummy;
// internally, nnil is the new nul
```

Что вот это значит?:

1. Создать тип `struct node` <s>`node` (оказывается имя типа всё-таки `struct node`)</s>
2. <s>`typedef struct node dumy`</s> Оказывается: объявить (глобальную?) переменную `dummy` содержащую помимо прочего массив состоящий из двух указателей на саму себя
3. `,` => `node* nnil =` опять указатель на эту `dummy`

Я прав? Это шо за синтаксис такой? C99? (смайлик "я в ужасе")

Comment: И коммент вообще добил. А вообще это отсюда: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/AVL_tree/C

Comment: Самый обычный "классический" синтаксис...

Comment: Да?? Ну я прав по поводу того что происходит?

Comment: Если особо не придираться, то да (правильно воспринимаете), только вместо термина ссылка в Си используется термин *указатель* (pointer).

Comment: А Ваш код, @avp кстати мне помог (в том числе) закрыть сессию! ))) (У вас в интернете лежит List с merge_sort я его и скопипастил) Вот как всё пересекается ) а я увидел никнэйм сразу вспомнил про старого доброго участника Хэшкода <s>ну вообще говоря не сессию (там надо матан и диффуры которые я досих пор не закрыл) а лишь (причём лишь один - их два - это "основы ос" легкотня а вот "алгоритмы и структуры данных")  программирование</s>

Comment: Очень приятно, что помог. Где и на кого учитесь, @Rules?

Comment: @Rules: Имя типа тут именно `struct node`, а не `node`, т.е. ваш первый пункт верен с точностью до наоборот.

Comment: Это вы дерево собираетесь строить? (По идее указатели там должны именоваться left, right, parent) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

Comment: @avp - БФУ прикладная матем и информатика.

Comment: @AnT - да, я понял. Вообще:
2)Сбалансированное бинарное дерево поиска(AVL, Красно-чёрное) 
Операции: 
Добавление элемента, удаление, поиск, балансировка.

Comment: @Rules, отлично, желаю успехов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
struct node {
```

Объявили структуру

```
} dummy
```

Создали переменную типа `struct node`

```
= {0, 0,
```

Первые два поля переменной `dummy` - нули (`dummy.payload = dummy.height = 0`)

```
{&dummy, &dummy}}
```

Элементам массива `kid` (указателям) присвоили адреса переменной `dummy` (`dummy.kid[0] = dummy.kid[1] = &dummy`)

```
, *nnil
```

Создали ещё одну переменную - указатель на переменную типа `struct dummy`

```
= &dummy;
```

Присвоили ей адрес переменной `dummy`

Всё, никаких хитростей, чистый C безо всяких наворотов.

Comment: @Rules, нет, это "чистый" C. C99 (более поздний стандарт) как раз в конце ответа VladFromMoscow.

Comment: @PinkTux: Во-первых, С99 - это такой же "чистый" С, как и любой другой С. Во-вторых, невозможно сказать, требуется ли тут С99, не видя контекста объявления. Если это *локальное* объявление, то формально оно не может быть сделано в С89/90, т.к. С89/90 не разрешит использование `&dummy` внутри агрегатного инициализатора. В С89/90 внутри агрегатных инициализаторов допускаются только константы времени компиляции. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5a6fa523f148963

Comment: @AnT, это не ошибки. Без `-pedantic-errors` прекрасно всё переваривается и в `-std=c90`, и в `-std=c89`. И инициализируется: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2489f3a854c6f24e

Comment: @PinkTux: Это именно *ошибки*. А то, что "все переваривается" без `-pedantic-errors` ничего не значит. `-pedantic-errors` для того и предназначен, чтобы выявлять такие ошибки. Требование стандарта я привел выше. Другое дело, что подобное расширение было весьма популярно в С89/90, но именно для подавления подобных "популярных расширений" у нас  и есть `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 7):

В этой конструкции сразу же объявляется структура, объект этой структуры и указатель на объект этой структуры.

Чтобы это объявление

```
struct node {
    int payload;
    int height;
    struct node *kid[2];
} dummy = {0, 0, {&dummy, &dummy}}, *nnil = &dummy;
```

было более понятным, вы можете его разбить на несколько объявлений. Исходное объявление эквивалентно следующим объявлениям.

```
struct node {
    int payload;
    int height;
    struct node *kid[2];
};

struct node dummy = {0, 0, {&dummy, &dummy}};
struct node *nnil = &dummy;
```

То есть объявляется структура с именем `struct node`. Затем объявляется объект этой структуры с именем `dummy` и его поля, как объекта структуры, инициализируются соответствующими значениями. Чтобы это объявление было еще более понятным, вы можете даже его переписать в C99 как

```
struct node dummy = { .payload = 0, .height = 0, .kid = { [0] = &dummy, [1] = &dummy }};
```

В этом объявлении объекта `dummy` его член данных `kid`, который представляет собой массив указателей, инициализируется адресом самого объекта `dummy`.

И, наконец, в третьем объявлении объявляется указатель с именем `nnil` на объект `dummy`

Comment: И даже не знаешь чей ответ "принять".. Или вообще удалить мой вопрос? (Стыдно теперь стало задавать такое и еще выбирать из эквивалентных ответов.. Но вы не обижайтесь ежели что - у вас тоже ответ хороший).)

Comment: @Rules Зачем удалять вопрос? Он полезен для других посетителей этого сайта.:)

Comment: О! VB'шные фишки в Си! Круто, не знал :)

Comment: ИМХО `struct node dummy *nnil = &dummy;` надо поправить на `struct node *nnil = &dummy;`